# Visual Studio 2015: Unit Test item not available in Unit Test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

VS never ceases to amaze me with unexpected behavior.

I'm using VS 2015 Ent., mostly for class librararies and unit test projects.

Just now I created a new Solution. The solution has a Windows Form project and a Unit Test project (selected types when creating he new projects in the solution).

In the Unit Test project, there is the usual default UnitTest1.cs class file. However, when I try to add New Item to the project, there is no Unit Test under the Visual C# meny entry. Also no shortcut to create a new Unit Test when right-clicking the Unit Test project, as it used to be. Even if I search for "Unit Test" in the New Item window, I get zero results.

Still, the project is a Unit Test project.

Anyone got any ideas/suggestions about this?

UPDATE:

I just noticed: VS seems to insist on creating a Windows 8.1 project, even though I create a Windows -> Unit Test Library (Windows) project.

It's listed in the solution explorer as

```
CalcTest (Windows 8.1)
```

Whereas in my other solution, when I create the same project, it's just listed with the project name. And in the other project, when right-clicking on the project -> Add -> I get "Unit Test" along with a bunch of other options. In this project, I get nothing, and Unit Test is nowhere to be found,

And there are other problems: I'm unable to install, for example, the ExpectedObjects package, as this cannot be installed in a Windows 8.1 project.

Comment: Another way to create unit tests is to choose "create unit" in the context menu when editing a public class. Is the "create unit" option shown when you right click in a public class text?

Comment: Heh. Yes, it is. So I'm able to select create Unit Test from the Windows application project, and chose to create it in the Unit Test project. But I'm not able to select create Unit Test in the Unit Test project itself.

Comment: I prefer to create the test units from the class. It's more complicated to specify the project etc., but creates some things by default, such as references if not established. Anyway in the community version I can add units to the test project, and I don't know why you can't in the enterprise version. I hope someone else answers you. Good luck.

Comment: Add a new class. Decorate the class with the [TestClass] attribute and decorate test methods with the [TestMethod] attribute and it should work. If the appropriate namespaces are not referenced the try pressing Ctrl+. when the cursor is over the declaration in question.